# What is $ Y:= \phi ( \mathbb{R^2}) $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R^2} \to  \mathbb{R^2}: (x,y) \to (e^x +y , e^y + y)$

The Task is to determine $ Y:= \phi (\mathbb{R^2})$
and Show that $\phi: \mathbb{R^2} \to Y $
is a homeomorphism.

My question is: What is Y here??

Comment: $Y$ is the image set or range of the map $\phi$. You know what the domain of $\phi$ is, and the mapping 'function'.

Comment: $Y=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ a>f(b)\}$, where $f$ is the inverse of $y\mapsto e^y+y$. So, if you take the graph of $y=e^x+x$, take is symmetry with respect to the line $y=x$ and consider the lower half of the plane delimited by the resulting curve, that is $Y$.

Comment: A picture is the symmetric of [this one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Ee%5Ex%2Bx) with respect to the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the range of $\phi$. 
In the notation $f: X \to Y$, the symbol $X$ means the domain of $f$ and $Y$ the codomain of $f$. Note that $Y \supset f(X)$ by convention. Note also that $f(X)$ is the value of the map $f: 2^{X} \to 2^{Y}$ at $X$. Although the same notation $f$ denotes two distinct functions, the context should always make things clear and thus same notation would hardly cause confusion.